# CSS Ids that share a common class

Tags: css, class, inheritance

I have an id named: mtl_navBtn[1-3] that contains a class called: "x-button-label". I'm trying to define css for that combination without repeating css styles like I did below , but I can't seem to get it right. I tried: #mtl_navBtn1,#mtl_navBtn2,#mtl_navBtn3  .x-button-label but it didn't work. I'm sure I'm missing something easy here...

```
<div id="mtl_navBtn1" class="x-button x-iconalign-left x-button-plain" style="margin-top: -30px; width: 52px !important; height: 225px !important;"><span id="ext-element-40" class="x-badge" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span class="x-button-icon etl_nav_btn etl_nav_btn_1_0_active" id="ext-element-42" style="">
    </span><span id="ext-element-41" class="x-button-label" style="">Label</span>
    </div> 





 #mtl_navBtn1 .x-button-label{
        width: 50px         !important;
        height: 50px        !important;
        margin-left: -47px  !important;
    }
    #mtl_navBtn2 .x-button-label{
        width: 50px         !important;
        height: 50px        !important;
        margin-left: -47px  !important;
    }
    #mtl_navBtn3 .x-button-label{
        width: 50px         !important;
        height: 50px        !important;
        margin-left: -47px  !important;
    }
```

Comment: The `!important` flag should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.  Try using using a more specific selector instead (see: css specificity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these will slim down your CSS:

```
#mtl_navBtn1 .x-button-label,
#mtl_navBtn2 .x-button-label,
#mtl_navBtn3 .x-button-label {
    // styles
}
```

or

```
[id^="mtl_navBtn"] .x-button-label {
    // styles
}
```

The first option has greater specificity than the second option, something to keep in mind if you're overwriting styles.

Comment: I knew it was something so simple I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
.x-button-label {
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    margin-left: -47px !important;
}
```

Comment: Good question... I should have mentioned I'm using Sencha and .x-button-label is their class and I dont want to override all  .x-button-label just the ones with specific IDs tied to them